# How would I edit the nth character on the nth line of a txt file (C++)

Tags: c++

Let's say my txt file looks like this:

```
-----
-----
-----
```

And I wanted to change it into something like this:

```
-----
-----
---+-
```

This'd be the 4th character of the 3rd line. What would be a simple way to do it? I've tried to use getline(), and my code looked something like this:

```
std::string line = file.getline(line, 1);
line[2] = '+';
//and then insert the content
```

It gave me the following error:
`no matching member function for call to 'getline'`

Comment: How did it fail? What did you try until now?

Comment: @GabeRAMturn I used something like this: ```std::string line = file.getline(line, 1);```

Comment: Ok, could you update the question? And how did it fail? Could you add that to the question too?

Comment: The title of the thread is misleading.  The issue has nothing to do with getting the nth character on the nth line.  It has everything to do with using [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie std::getline might not even be the correct way to do this in this case.

Comment: Why does your code suggest it is trying to change the third character of the first (maybe intended to be second?) line of some file to a `j`, but your explanation refers to a different character of a different line and changing it to a `+`? Consistency is important for being understood.

Comment: @H.A. All `std::getline` does is read the line from a file.  You then need to write the logic to keep track of what line, and thus what character to change.  Try a `while` loop and `getline`.  Note that you didn't even get past the compilation stage.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
std::string line = file.getline(line, 1);
```

does not make sense, for several reasons:

1. The second argument of the function [`file.getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) requires an argument of type `char *`, not `std::string`. If you want to use `getline` with a `std::string`, then you probably want to use the free function [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of the member function `std::istream:getline` described above.
2. The return value of `file.getline` is a reference to the stream, not the content of the retrieved input.
3. Passing `1` as the second argument will only read a single character, which is probably not what you want.

If you want to use `std::getline`, then you can use the following code instead:

```
std::string line;
std::getline( file, line );
```

In order to ignore input, you can also use the function [`file.ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

In order to skip the first two lines of the file, you can call the following statement twice (for example in a loop):

```
file.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

Note that you will have to `#include <limits>` in order to use [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

In order to skip three characters of input, you can call the following statement three times:

```
file.ignore();
```

To write a character at that position, you can then use the function [`file.put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put).

Note that the stream will have to have been opened for both reading and writing for this to work.